# Android Facebook API not sending APP Requests

Tags: android, facebook

I am using the Android Hackbook app. I have slightly modified the code to send a app request to a a Custom Friend. Here is the code.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("title", "invite friends");
    params.putString("message", getString(R.string.request_message));
    params.putString("to", userId);
    Utility.mFacebook.dialog(Hackbook.this, "apprequests", params, new AppRequestsListener());
```

This brings up a dialog to send a app request to the friend who user id i selected. The AppRequestsListener code gets executed and it shows me a  toast that the request was successful. How the user never receives the request. What am i doing wrong. Is there some permission that i need to grant to the application  first. Really stuck, any help would be good

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Facebook facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID);
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("to", userId);
        params.putString("message", "getString(R.string.request_message)");
        facebook.dialog(((Activity) ctx).getParent(), "apprequests",
                params, new DialogListener() {

                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, "<<Complete>>",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

                    public void onCancel() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }

        });
```

This works for me. User receive request as expected.

Comment: did you submit your app to the app center, first ??

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Of course you have to create an app on Facebook. Then you can get your app Id to use for your application